# Calculating the similarity of two histograms

Tags: calculus, analysis, algorithms

Supposing that I have the following histograms:

```
 Histogram1      Histogram2     Histogram3 

  X             X                      X X
  X   X         X       X X            X X
X X   X X X     X X   X X X    X X X X X X
0 1 2 3 4 5     0 1 2 3 4 5    0 1 2 3 4 5

Histogram1 = [ 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 1 ]
Histogram2 = [ 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2 ]
Histogram3 = [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3 ]
```

Now, given a new histogram:

```
NewHistogram  

  X     X    
X X     X    
X X X X X X
0 1 2 3 4 5

NewHistogram = [ 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1 ]
```

I want to calculate the similarity of each histogram based on the new one.

I am currently using the following formula that was found on [this topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7400/how-to-assess-the-similarity-of-two-histograms/151362#151362).

Euclidean Distance

$D_{L2} = \sqrt{\sum_{i}\left( h_1(i) - h_2(i) \right) ^2 }$

As you can see on the topic referenced there is a lot of formulas that can be used. I have chosen the Euclidean distance because it is easy to apply and it is used in various applications.

Now I have two doubts:

1. Is this a good/correct way to calculate the similarity of two
   histograms?
2. There is a better (and easy) way to calculate it?

**Note 1**: I'm using it to compare two images (related to image processing).

**Note 2**: I'm not a mathematician, I'm a software engineering, so don't have much knowledge in this area.

**Note 3**: I could not find a good tag for this question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A seemingly good track is to consider working on "cumulated histograms"  [2,5,6,7,10,11] in your last example (just as working on the cdf $F$ instead of the pdf $f$) and use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov distribution/test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)

Comment: Depending on your application, you might want to assign weights to the quality of the match at 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and/or 5. You can then define a more general Mahalanobis distance instead of an Euclidean one. Kullbach-Leibler distance is often employed for comparing distributions.